# N1qlQuery.Consistency.Request_Plus

Tags: node.js, couchbase, sql++

```
RecordModel.getAll = function(callback){
    var statement = 'SELECT META(users).id,firstname,lastname,email FROM default AS users';
    var query= N1qlQuery.fromString(statement).consistency(N1qlQuery.Consistency.REQUEST_PLUS);
    db.query(query,function(error,result){
        if(error){
            return callback(error,null);
        }
        callback(null,result);
    });
```

Error :  Cannot read property "REQUEST_PLUS" of undefined.

Comment: can You do `console.log(N1qlQuery)` at line above of `var query` ?  or try to use as: `N1qlQuery.fromString(statement).consistency(2)`.  also are You sure that `N1qlQuery` is defined in Your current file?

Comment: consistency(2) gave error saying SELECT META(users).id,firstname,lastname,email FROM default AS users'; has no method "consistency"

Comment: seems like Your query does not work as expected. Have You tried to execute Your query in couchbase's web interface?

Comment: I havent tried on web interface.  Same is the problem with   :               

var N1qlQuery = require('couchbase').N1qlQuery;
var myBucket = myCluster.openBucket();
myBucket.enableN1ql('host');
var query = N1qlQuery.fromString('SELECT * FROM default');
myBucket.query(query,function(err, res) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('query failed', err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('success!',res);
});                                                                                                      where error is : failed to parse the query response as json.

Comment: http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/getting-started/first-n1ql-query.html

Comment: try to run Your query in query workbench: http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/tools/query-workbench.html#topic_prr_nyh_t5

Answer (score 0):

Have you done this:

`var N1qlQuery = require('couchbase').N1qlQuery;`

If not, then you're trying to get the REQUEST_PLUS value from the wrong place.